# OMake compilation with sub-directories

Tags: c++, omake

Looking through OMake documentation it seems whenever sources from subdirectories are used - they are always compiled into static libraries first. Is this always necessary? Can I compile and link everything without building the libs? I've been trying to write OMakefiles for this but with no success.

**Example dir structure:**

myproject:    OMakeroot, OMakefile, main.cpp

myproject/headers: file1.h

myproject/src: file1.cpp

---

**myproject OMakeroot contents:**

open build/C

.SUBDIRS: .

**myproject Omakefile contents:**

CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS =  -Wall

INCLUDES += headers src

CXXProgram(myapp, main file1 )

---

OMakefiles in headers and src directories are empty, not sure if anything needs to be in them.

When I run omake myapp I get an error:

**Do not know how to build "file1.o" required for "myapp"**

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, in case the thread disappears, here is the solution posted on the thread that [Maxicat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137660) refers to (reworded to show just the solution).

> It is *not* the case that you have to compile into static libraries, but
>   the default assumption is that each object file goes into the same
>   directory as the source file.
>
> <s>INCLUDES += headers src</s>
>
> INCLUDES is only for the header files. You need
>
> ```
> INCLUDES += $(dir headers)
> .SUBDIRS: src
> ```
>
> (Note1 - the order of the previous two lines is important. The way I
>   wrote it, the src dir would get the updated INCLUDES; if you do not want
>   that, reorder the two.)
>
> (Note2 - the above would expect an src/OMakefile file, even though an
>   empty one would do. You could write something like
>
> ```
> .SUBDIRS: src
>    return # A no-op body
> ```
>
> to "inline" the ./src/OMakefile into the ./OMakefile)
>
> <s>CXXProgram(myapp, main file1 )</s>
>
> Should be
>
> ```
> CXXProgram(myapp, main src/file1)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try `src/file1`, so that omake knows that it needs to build `src/file1.o` instead of `file1.o`, and therefore needs `src/file1.cpp` instead of `file1.cpp` (which doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Got this resolved on the Omake mailing list, thread link here just for completeness: http://lists.metaprl.org/pipermail/omake/2009-July/002094.html